# If $B $ is closed in the subspace $Y $ of $X $, does $B = \overline B \cap Y $

Tags: general-topology

I have two questions

I know that if $Y $ is closed in $X $ then $ B = Y \cap C$ for som $C $ closed in $X $. What if $Y $ isn't closed.

1) If $B $ is closed in the subspace $Y $ of $X $, can it be open in $X $? (It musn't be closed at least: take $B= [0,1 )$, $Y= (-1,1) $)

2) Assume $B$ is a subset of $Y $, closed in the subspace $Y $ of $X $, does it follow that $B = \overline B \cap Y $, where $\overline B $ is the closure of $B $ in $X $. (Here the only difference between  $\overline B \cap Y $ and $  B \cap Y $ must be when $B \subset Y $ but $\overline B \not \subset Y$, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the subspace topology, $B\subset Y$ is closed in $Y$ if and only if there is a closed $C \subset X$ such that $B = C\cap Y$. This definition does not impose any conditions on $Y$, it is the same whether $Y$ is open, closed, both, or neither.

> 1) If $B$ is closed in the subspace $Y$ of $X$, can it be open in $X$?

Note that in every topological space, there are at least two subsets that are open and closed at the same time. There are also topological spaces where every subset is open.

> 2) Assume $B$ is a subset of $Y$, closed in the subspace $Y$ of $X$, does it follow that $B = \overline{B}\cap Y$, where $\overline{B}$ is the closure of $B$ in $X$.

Clearly, $B \subset \overline{B}\cap Y$. Also, we know there is a closed (in $X$) $C$ with $B = C\cap Y$. What follows about the relation of $C$ and $\overline{B}$, and then about $\overline{B}\cap Y$?

Comment: Thanks!, so for instance in 1) we could have $B $ both open and closed in $Y $ and $Y $ open in $X $, then $B $ would be open in $X $.

Comment: for 2) $B \subset Y  \implies B \subset \overline B \cap Y$.

Now $B = C \cap Y \implies B \subset C \implies \overline B \subset C \implies \overline B \cap Y \subset C \cap Y = B$. Hence equality

Comment: Yes, that's right. For 1), note that if $B$ is open in $X$, then it is also open in $Y$, so it must be both open and closed in $Y$ in that situation. Then if we take $B$ clopen in $Y$, it is sufficient, but not necessary that $Y$ is open in $X$ for $B$ to be open in $X$. And if we take a discrete space for $X$, everything is open and closed anyway.