# If $Y$ is closed in the subspace topology of $A$, then $\overline{Y} \cap A = Y$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y \subset A \subset X$ with $Y$ closed in the subspace topology of $A$. Show that $\overline{Y} \cap A = Y$.

I realise that by the assumption that $Y$ is closed in the subset-topology we can write
$Y = A \cap U \text{, with $U \subset X$ closed in $X$}$, so we have $$\overline{Y} \cap A = \overline{A \cap U} \cap A.$$

However, I do not see how to continue from here. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $B $ is closed in the subspace $Y $ of $X $, does $B = \overline B \cap Y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046340/if-b-is-closed-in-the-subspace-y-of-x-does-b-overline-b-cap-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Cl_X(Y)$ denote the closure of $Y$ in $X$, and $Cl_A(Y)$ the closure of $Y$ in $A$. As $Y$ is closed in $A$, $Cl_A(Y)=Y$.

Obviously, $Y \subseteq Cl_X(Y) \cap A$. For the other inclusion, let $z \in Cl_X(Y) \cap A$. We'll show that $z \in Cl_A(Y)=Y$ (here we use that $Y$ is closed in $A$). Indeed, let $U$ be an $A$-open neighbourhood of $z$. Then, there exists an $X$-open set $V \subseteq X$ such that $U = V \cap A$. Note that $V$ is an $X$-open neighbourhood of $z$ and, as $z \in Cl_X(Y)$, $\emptyset \neq V \cap Y = V \cap Y \cap A = U \cap Y$. Therefore, $z \in Cl_A(Y)=Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$Y\subset A\subset X$

Claim: $\textrm{cl}_X(Y)\cap A=\textrm{cl}_A(Y) \tag{1}$

Proof:
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/901291/977780).

$Y\subset A$ closed in $(A, \tau_A) $ implies $\textrm{cl}_A(Y)=Y \tag{2}$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ $$\textrm{cl}(Y)\cap A=\textrm{cl}_A(Y)=Y $$